# Is this an example of comaximal ideals $I,J$ such that $IJ\not=I\cap J$?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, free-groups

Let $R$ denote the set of all finite formal sums of elements in the free group $\left<a,b\right>$ with the relation $a+b=1.$ Let $I$ be the principle ideal generated by $a$ and $J$ the principle ideal generated by $b.$ It follows that $ba\in I\cap J,$ however, $ba\not\in IJ.$

The fact that $ba\not\in IJ$ follows from if 
$$\sum_{i=1}^mw_i\in I$$
where $w_i$ are words in $a,b,$ then by definition each $w_i$ contains $a.$ Similarly if 
$$\sum_{j=1}^mv_i\in J,$$
then each $v_i$ contains $b$. Then 
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^mw_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^mv_i\right)=\sum_{i,j}w_iv_j,$$
and each $w_iv_j$ has an $a$ to the left of a $b.$ So
$\sum_{i,j}w_iv_j\not=ba.$

Clearly $I+J=R$ as $a+b\in I+J$ and $a+b=1.$

Comment: Doesn't the relationship $a=1-b$ mean it's not necessarily so that each word in your first sum contains an $a$?  Isn't $1-b$ an example of a word that's in $I$ that doesn't use $a$?

Comment: @Robert Shore Yes. Thank you. Back to the drawing board.